# How to switch between view and controller MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am new to asp.net mvc.I want to execute following scenario.

I  have a form to calculate simple interest.After filling the form i want to display the simple interest value below that form.I have passed the entered values to the controller and calculated simple interest value.The problem is how to display that value below that form after the user clicks Calculate.

My form structure is as follows:

- Amount
- Rate
- Year
- Calculate

After clicking on calculate,i want to display simple interest value below that form.

My code is as follows:

**Controller**

```
    public ActionResult SimpleInterest()
    {
        SimpleInterestModel model = new SimpleInterestModel();
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CalculateSimpleInterestResult(SimpleInterestModel model)
    {
        decimal simpleInteresrt = (model.Amount * model.Year * model.Rate) / 100;
        StringBuilder sbInterest = new StringBuilder();
        sbInterest.Append("<b>Amount :</b> " + model.Amount + "<br/>");
        sbInterest.Append("<b>Rate :</b> " + model.Rate + "<br/>");
        sbInterest.Append("<b>Time(year) :</b> " + model.Year + "<br/>");
        sbInterest.Append("<b>Interest :</b> " + simpleInteresrt);
        return Content(sbInterest.ToString());
    }
```

**View**

```
     <div class="container" style="width:30%">
    <h2>Calulate Simple Interest</h2>
    @using (@Html.BeginForm("CalculateSimpleInterestResult", "Test", FormMethod.Post))
    {

        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Amount, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Amount" })
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Rate, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Rate" })
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Year, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Year" })


        <input type="submit" value="Calculate" class="btn-block" />

    }
    </div>
```

**Model**

```
public class SimpleInterestModel
{
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
    public decimal Rate { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Use ajax to call the server method that returns a partial view of the results and in the success call back, add that partial to the DOM (or you could return a `JsonResult` containing the values to update)

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate simple interest using jquery on button click event, and show result in same view.

```js
function calculateSimpleInterest() {
 var loSimpleInterest = parseFloat(parseFloat($('#Amount').val())*parseFloat($('#Year').val())*parseFloat($('#Rate').val()))/100;
 $('#Result').text('Simple Interest: ' + loSimpleInterest)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
Amount: <input type="text" id="Amount"><br/><br/>
Rate: <input type="text" id="Rate"><br/><br/>
Year: <input type="text" id="Year"><br/><br/>

<input type="submit" value="Calculate" id="Calculate" onclick="calculateSimpleInterest();" />
<br/><br/>
<label id="Result"></label>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few possibilities. 
One way is to extend the Model with something like `public int SimpleInteresrt {get;set;}` and return the model to another view that displays the model data.

Or you can pass the `simpleInteresrt` value into the Viewbag an read it in the View via razor. You have just place under the form a Razor-Code that checks if the Viewbag is null or not, and if not, then display the value.

In your View something like this:

```
@{
   int? simple = Viewbag.Simple;
   if( simple.HasValue )
   {
     @: Your Value is: @simple.Value
   }
  }
```

And in your Controller you add after calculation something like this

```
Viewbag.Simple = simpleInteresrt;
```

Another way is to use asynchronous JavaScript calls (AJAX). Where you Post Data to your Controller vie JavaScript and receive a JSON-Answer, that you use to manipulate your DOM.

Comment: Thanks a lot.Finally after combining your idea and my idea,i got the desired result.